# There are $5$ boys and $5$ girls. Find the ways in which boy and girl can sit alternately.

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $5$ boys and $5$ girls. Find the ways in which boy and girl can sit alternately.

I think it is $$5!×\binom65\times5!$$
I used this method: First let the boys sit in 5 places:
BBBBB and they have $5!$ ways to be arranged.
And we have 6 places left for girls as _B_B_B_B_B_

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are they sitting in a line or in a circle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't 6 choose 5.  In order to actually sit alternatively, there are only two such ways; either GB GB GB GB GB or BG BG BG BG BG.  Thus, it is $2(5!)^2$.