# Arrangement of 4 boys and 4 girls with no two girls are next to each other?

Tags: permutations

Let we have 4 boys and 4 girls and we need to arrange them, with no two boys and no two girls are next to each other?
Let place first the boys

```
b b b b
```

the 4 boys can arrange themselves by 4! ways. Now we have 5 positions between boys but we have  4 girls. If we  arrange them like  $5^{P}4 = 5!$ then the total arrangement will be = $5! \times 4!$

But there is a problem,

If we think, `g b g b g b  (*) b`

In the above style  we have a boy and boy  repetition. How to solve this problem?

Comment: If no two boys can be adjacent, and no two girls can be adjacent, the arrangement have to alternate BGBGBGBG, or GBGBGBGB. There are $4!^2$ ways to create each configuration.

Comment: We are having the two different patterns so , will not we have to multiply 2 ?    = $2\times 4!  \times 4!  $ ?

Comment: Yes, the final answer should be $2\times 4!^2=1152$

Comment: Your calculation gives the answer to the question in the title, which is not the same as the question in the body.

Comment: Similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733427/there-are-5-boys-and-5-girls-find-the-ways-in-which-boy-and-girl-can-sit-al?rq=1